# Firebase User Properties not seeming to be removed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Using the following code:

```
Analytics.setUserProperty(newValue?["Id"] as? String, forName: "favorite_coach_id")
```

I am able to set this Firebase User Property which seems to be properly associated with subsequent events. However when the value parameter is nil, although I see this in the Debug Console:

> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023075] Removing user property. Name:
>   favorite_coach_id

which is the desired behavior, I still see subsequent events that come through in the Firebase Debug View being associated with the previous property value and nothing appears to have been "removed". Am I not understanding something correctly, or is there a bug somewhere?

EDIT: After doing some more testing, it seems that the User Property cleared for me on a new session_start event, I'm not sure this is early enough to be working as expected though

Comment: Properties are maintained per user session to limit memory/bandwidth usage, so it sounds like this may be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a custom property occurs when you try to set the nil as a value. Check your dictionary "newValue? [" Id "] as? String, maybe at some point in time there is no value there or is it of a different type